# Get image after add clipboard on uploaded image in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am uploading image in canvas. I have restricted the area of the image using a clipboard. After the submit button is clicked, I want to get the full image of canvas and separate upload image. Right now i am getting image of canvas and not the separate uploaded image. What i want, I will put in screen shots.

[image]

After rotate image.
[image]

After click on submit button:
[image]

But i also want separate modified flower image.
Expected result in below screen shot.
[image]

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
$("#canvascolor > input").click(function() {
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(this.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });
});
// trigger the first one at startup
$("#canvascolor > input:first-of-type()")[0].click();
function clipTShirt(ctx) {
   ctx.save();
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   var x = 140, y = 100 ,w = 225, h = 300;
   ctx.moveTo(x, y);
   ctx.lineTo(x + w, y);
   ctx.lineTo(x + w, y + h);
   ctx.lineTo(x, y + h);
   ctx.lineTo(x, y);
   ctx.restore();
}
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  console.log("reader   " + reader);
  reader.onload = function(f) {
    var data = f.target.result;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
      var oImg = img.set({
        left: 140,
        top: 100,
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        angle: 0,
        lockUniScaling: true,
        centeredScaling: true,
        clipTo: clipTShirt
      }).scale(0.9);
       oImg.lockMovementX = true;
     
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.8
      });
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
document.querySelector('#txt').onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();
  document.querySelector('#preview').src = canvas.toDataURL();
};
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#canvascolor input {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
   <input type="file" id="file">
<canvas id="canvas" width="520" height="520"></canvas>
<section id="canvascolor">
  <input class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/9leyl96qd3tytn8/tshirt-front.jpg">
  <input class="canvasborder" type="image" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tk0fs5v4muo6898/tshirt-back.jpg">
</section>
<button href='' id='txt' target="_blank">submit</button><br/>
<img id="preview" />
```

Comment: Are you really sending all the new steps of your project in here without ever trying to learn by yourself how to do things??? Remove the background before calling a second time`.renderAll().toDataURL()`...

Comment: @Kaiido. First i tried every things, But i am new in HTML5 and fabric js, Then i have some problem.

Comment: But I am concerned about the fact you do learn anything from all these `Please give me the codez` questions. I could give it directly to you, but will this really help you? Actually, if you had wrote your question with "How to remove a previously set background-image", I would have known you actually do understand something from what we did tell you in all your questions, and I would already have answered.

Comment: Ps, the images you do use in this question are from my personal dropbox account, I may delete these at some point so you would be better creating your own dropbox account and upload these again.

Comment: @Kaiido. You mean i need to remove my uploaded image.

Comment: Thanks to Kaiido and MarkE. I should read the Fabric js again. Thanks your guidance.

Comment: No, in first comment I told you to remove the backgroundImage (actually you just need to hide it) that you should have learned how to set in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945050/uploaded-image-display-with-background-image-after-click-on-button-from-canvas-h/34946328). My last comment is about the `front.png` and `back.png` images that I do host on my personal dropbox account. This is just for posterity of your posts, letting you know that I may delete it at some point in the future.

Comment: Is not first user submitting every step of his project. i'm curios as well if they remember any answer after a week. As a mantainer of fabricjs i'm happy to see questions answered for next people coming.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, as I told OP, if there were some point in his question that shown he did understand where his problem is, I would have answered with great pleasure. As it is, he doesn't.  Stackoverflow is not mean to be a new documentation for every libraries. This question as it is, is too specific for anyone coming in the future to find help from it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2686/how-should-you-respond-to-give-me-a-fish-rtfm-questions

Comment: of course i was not pointing at you @Kaiido, i did not reply as well for the same reasons.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi but to write nice self-answered questions about Fabricjs, which would really help future readers, you're more than welcome!

Comment: @Kaiido, you mean i do everything Q and A? i never tought about that... i feel so dumb now.

Comment: Sorry  you guys. I think i am troubling you. This is not my motive guys.